# How to convert multi module project to a single module in Android Studio?

Tags: android, module, multi-module

I developed an android project that has 2 android modules (one of them is the openCVLibrary310 module). Now I want to create a module from my whole project that contains my own classes and 2 modules.
in other word I want to merge 2 modules and my project to one module

My first question is : Is it possible to convert the modules that were not for me and enter the project into a module in addition to my own project?

If yes, how to do it?

Comment: Hi did you find any answer yet?